# PIVOT entire column set by group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

For a table like:

```
COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4
item1   7/29/13 cat     blue
item3   7/29/13 fish    purple
item1   7/30/13 rat     green
item2   7/30/13 bat     grey
item3   7/30/13 bird    orange
```

How would you PIVOT to get rows by COL2, all other columns repeated across as blocks by COL1 values?

```
COL2    COL1    COL3    COL4    COL1    COL3    COL4    COL1    COL3    COL4
7/29/13 item1   cat     blue    item2   NULL    NULL    item3   fish    purple
7/30/13 item1   rat     green   item2   bat     grey    item3   bird    orange
```

Comment: (Or better as iterated joins on itself)?

Comment: Last comment: number of items may change (may add a few more - but count is not >10) - so a static series of joins of the table to itself over each item value is not ideal.  Thanks!

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the application level code/presentation layer if you have one (e.g. passing an ordered result set to a PHP loop). It's much more flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get this result you will need to do a few things:

1. get a distinct list of values from `col1` and `col2`
2. unpivot the data in your columns `col1`, `col3` and `col4`
3. pivot the result from the unpivot

To get the distinct list of dates and items (col1 and col2) along with the values from your existing table you will need to use something similar to the following:

```
select t.col1, t.col2,
  t2.col3, t2.col4,
  row_number() over(partition by t.col2
                      order by t.col1) seq
from 
(
  select distinct t.col1, c.col2
  from yourtable t
  cross join 
  (
    select distinct col2
    from yourtable
  ) c
) t
left join yourtable t2
  on t.col1 = t2.col1
  and t.col2 = t2.col2;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/471ab/16).  Once you have this list, then you will need to unpivot the data. There are several ways you can do this, using the UNPIVOT function or using CROSS APPLY:

```
select d.col2,
  col = col+'_'+cast(seq as varchar(10)),
  value
from
(
  select t.col1, t.col2,
    t2.col3, t2.col4,
    row_number() over(partition by t.col2
                        order by t.col1) seq
  from 
  (
    select distinct t.col1, c.col2
    from yourtable t
    cross join 
    (
      select distinct col2
      from yourtable
    ) c
  ) t
  left join yourtable t2
    on t.col1 = t2.col1
    and t.col2 = t2.col2
) d
cross apply
(
  select 'col1', col1 union all
  select 'col3', col3 union all
  select 'col4', col4 
) c (col, value);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/471ab/17). this will give you data that looks like:

```
|                        COL2 |    COL |  VALUE |
-------------------------------------------------
| July, 29 2013 00:00:00+0000 | col1_1 |  item1 |
| July, 29 2013 00:00:00+0000 | col3_1 |    cat |
| July, 29 2013 00:00:00+0000 | col4_1 |   blue |
| July, 29 2013 00:00:00+0000 | col1_2 |  item2 |
| July, 29 2013 00:00:00+0000 | col3_2 | (null) |
| July, 29 2013 00:00:00+0000 | col4_2 | (null) |
```

Finally, you will apply the PIVOT function to the items in the `col` columns:

```
select col2, 
  col1_1, col3_1, col4_1, 
  col1_2, col3_2, col4_2, 
  col1_3, col3_3, col4_3
from
(
  select d.col2,
    col = col+'_'+cast(seq as varchar(10)),
    value
  from
  (
    select t.col1, t.col2,
      t2.col3, t2.col4,
      row_number() over(partition by t.col2
                          order by t.col1) seq
    from 
    (
      select distinct t.col1, c.col2
      from yourtable t
      cross join 
      (
        select distinct col2
        from yourtable
      ) c
    ) t
    left join yourtable t2
      on t.col1 = t2.col1
      and t.col2 = t2.col2
  ) d
  cross apply
  (
    select 'col1', col1 union all
    select 'col3', col3 union all
    select 'col4', col4 
  ) c (col, value)
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in (col1_1, col3_1, col4_1, 
              col1_2, col3_2, col4_2, 
              col1_3, col3_3, col4_3)
)piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/471ab/18).  If you have an unknown number of values, then you can use dynamic SQL to get the result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(col+'_'+cast(seq as varchar(10))) 
                    from
                    (
                      select row_number() over(partition by col2
                                                  order by col1) seq
                      from yourtable
                    ) t
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select 'col1', 1 union all
                      select 'col3', 2 union all
                      select 'col4', 3
                    ) c (col, so)
                    group by col, seq, so
                    order by seq, so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT col2, ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
                select d.col2,
                  col = col+''_''+cast(seq as varchar(10)),
                  value
                from
                (
                  select t.col1, t.col2,
                    t2.col3, t2.col4,
                    row_number() over(partition by t.col2
                                        order by t.col1) seq
                  from 
                  (
                    select distinct t.col1, c.col2
                    from yourtable t
                    cross join 
                    (
                      select distinct col2
                      from yourtable
                    ) c
                  ) t
                  left join yourtable t2
                    on t.col1 = t2.col1
                    and t.col2 = t2.col2
                ) d
                cross apply
                (
                  select ''col1'', col1 union all
                  select ''col3'', col3 union all
                  select ''col4'', col4 
                ) c (col, value)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/471ab/21).  All versions will give a result:

```
|                        COL2 | COL1_1 | COL3_1 | COL4_1 | COL1_2 | COL3_2 | COL4_2 | COL1_3 | COL3_3 | COL4_3 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| July, 29 2013 00:00:00+0000 |  item1 |    cat |   blue |  item2 | (null) | (null) |  item3 |   fish | purple |
| July, 30 2013 00:00:00+0000 |  item1 |    rat |  green |  item2 |    bat |   grey |  item3 |   bird | orange |
```

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic `UNPIVOT`+`PIVOT` method is always cool, when doing this sort of thing for a known and limited set of values subsequent `JOIN`'s work nicely too (being lazy on the `SELECT` list):

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COL2 ORDER BY COL1)'RowRank'
             FROM  #Table1)
SELECT *
FROM  cte a
LEFT JOIN cte b
  ON a.COL2 = b.COL2
  AND a.RowRank = b.RowRank - 1
LEFT JOIN cte c
  ON b.COL2 = c.COL2
  AND b.RowRank = c.RowRank - 1
WHERE a.RowRank = 1
```

Or if the order of the fields is to be maintained:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT a.*,b.RowRank
             FROM  #Table1 a
             JOIN (SELECT Col1,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col1)'RowRank' 
                   FROM #Table1
                   GROUP BY COL1) b
                 ON a.Col1 = b.Col1)
SELECT *
FROM  cte a
LEFT JOIN cte b
  ON a.COL2 = b.COL2
  AND a.RowRank = b.RowRank - 1
LEFT JOIN cte c
ON a.COL2 = c.COL2
  AND a.RowRank = c.RowRank - 2
WHERE a.RowRank = 1
```

But this falls apart without an 'anchor' value, ie if no record had `item1` for a given date it wouldn't be included.

Comment: Any suggestions on keeping the values in the same order (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/471ab/25) meaning item1 columns, then item2 columns, etc?

Comment: Ah, yeah that would be a problem if order was important, could use a distinct list of Col1 values, but the subsequent `JOIN` method would fall apart if there was no anchor value.